# Parse-server on EB throwing 499 after creating new objects

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I have a parse server app, hosted on Elastic Beanstalk.

I have done the mistake of not deploying frequently enough, however since the last update after a new objet is created it will start throwing Nginx 499 errors, however static pages (which do not call the API) still get served

I have deleted all the cloud code and also trying to redeploy old versions of the app but it still keeps happening.

Any idea on how to go about debugging the issue?

Comment: We are also experiencing random 504 errors with 499 codes coming from nginx when attempting to interact with Parse. We haven't been able to pinpoint what is causing this, but it sounds like something similar.

Comment: It definitely is related to some change I have made, I see that the requests are to 127.0.0.1 on port 8081, but the server is running on 1337 but can't figure out where those requests are generated. Simple GET requests work fine, POST make parse unusable after a few minutes after the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem waasn't with Nginx but with a parse-server dependency:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1855

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following lines to /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf

```
proxy_connect_timeout 60;
proxy_send_timeout 60;
proxy_read_timeout 60;
```

then restart nginx, then restart your server

Comment: What does your database look like? We were using mLab's sandbox for our Dev/Test server and one of their paid clusters for our Live server. We were having these issues on the sandbox, but not the paid cluster. The above code may help alleviate the problem for a period of time, but it likely won't solve it. Upgrading our Dev/Test database to one of mLab's smaller (albeit paid) ended up getting rid of these issues for us. We actually contacted mLab and they verified this for us. The sandbox isn't meant to support large data sets/queries (even if you're not using all of the allotted 500MB).